# python numpy配列でshape(5, 5)の配列から、(5, 5, 4)配列を作る方法

Tags: python, numpy, array

pythonで(5, 5)の以下のような配列Xがあります。（数値は適当です。）

```
array([[59, 65, 57, 57, 62],
       [96, 81, 83, 83, 96],
       [53, 29, 30, 30, 53],
       [26,  0,  0,  0, 27],
       [20,  1,  5,  0, 19]], dtype=uint8)

X.shape  >>>(5, 5)
```

このような配列を4つ合わせてshape(5, 5, 4)の以下のような配列X2作成したいのですが方法が良くわかりません。

```
array([[[59, 35, 26, 54],
        [65, 17, 22, 1],
        [12, 27, 47, 21],
        [14, 17, 37, 41],
        [11, 36, 42, 11]],
　　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　　・
        [[20, 25, 10, 3],
        [ 1,  15, 21, 42],
        [ 5,  25, 11, 3],
        [ 0,  4, 10, 23],
        [12, 14, 11, 32]]], dtype=uint8)

X2.shape  >>>(5, 5, 4)
```

どうしたらこのような処理ができるのか、どなたかご教授お願いします。

以上.

**追記**
すみません。
元の2次元配列をそのまま3次元配列に並べる処理で、shapeは(4,5,5)になる形の処理でも大丈夫です。shapeの順番は問いません。
X2.shape  >>>(4, 5, 5)

Comment: 元の配列上の各数値が新しい配列の何処にどのように配置されるかの情報を追記してみてください。元の2次元配列をそのまま3次元配列に並べる処理だとshapeは(4,5,5)になるので、(5,5,4)にするためには何かしらの手順に従った変換処理が必要になるはずです。

Answer (score 1):

出来るshapeが(4,5,5)で良いのなら、このページの記事が参考になるでしょう。
[NumPy配列ndarrayを結合（concatenate, stack, blockなど）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-concatenate-stack-block/)

`numpy`の`stack()`で一気に出来ます。
`Xa`,`Xb`,`Xc`,`Xd`という4つの2次元配列があったとすると:

```
X2 = np.stack([Xa, Xb, Xc, Xd], 0)
```

1つづつあるいは複数同士を結合するなら`concatenate()`でしょうね。
1つづつ増やす:

```
X3 = np.stack([Xa, Xb], 0)
X3 = np.concatenate([X3, [Xc]])
X3 = np.concatenate([X3, [Xd]])
```

2つの3次元配列を結合

```
X4 = np.stack([Xa, Xb], 0)
X5 = np.stack([Xc, Xd], 0)
X4 = np.concatenate([X4, X5])
```

続けるとこんな感じに

```
import numpy as np

Xa = np.array([
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [6,7,8,9,10],
  [11,12,13,14,15],
  [16,17,18,19,20],
  [21,22,23,24,25]
], dtype=np.uint8)

Xb = np.array([
  [51,52,53,54,55],
  [56,57,58,59,60],
  [61,62,63,64,65],
  [66,67,68,69,60],
  [71,72,73,74,75]
], dtype=np.uint8)

Xc = np.array([
  [101,102,103,104,105],
  [106,107,108,109,110],
  [111,112,113,114,115],
  [116,117,118,119,120],
  [121,122,123,124,125]
], dtype=np.uint8)

Xd = np.array([
  [151,152,153,154,155],
  [156,157,158,159,160],
  [161,162,163,164,165],
  [166,167,168,169,160],
  [171,172,173,174,175]
], dtype=np.uint8)

X2 = np.stack([Xa, Xb, Xc, Xd], 0)
X2.shape

X3 = np.stack([Xa, Xb], 0)
X3 = np.concatenate([X3, [Xc]])
X3 = np.concatenate([X3, [Xd]])
X3.shape

X4 = np.stack([Xa, Xb], 0)
X5 = np.stack([Xc, Xd], 0)
X4 = np.concatenate([X4, X5])
X4.shape
```

---

ちなみに uint8 のデータ型とか4つをひとまとめにすることとかからすると、R,G,B,Aの4つのプレーン毎のデータを合わせてフルカラーデータを求める感じでしょうか。

そうすると当てはまるか(英語版はRGBの3つだけ)どうか不明ですが、こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。
[Combine 3 separate numpy arrays to an RGB image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10443295/9014308)
[Python, NumPyで画像処理（読み込み、演算、保存）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-image-processing/)
[NumPyでRGB画像の色チャンネルを分離して単色化、白黒化、色交換](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-rgb-image-split-color/) : 分離する逆の操作ですが
[How to extract R,G,B values with numpy into seperate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41500637/9014308) : こちらも逆方向かつRGB

OpenCVやPILにはそうした機能のメソッドがあるのかもしれません。